# Check if a value is empty

Tags: forms, post, asp-classic

I am working on a asp classic script and have a "honey pot" set up. I want to check if the value in the honey post is empty before proceeding with processing and sending off an email.

HTML:

```
<div class="jam_jar" style="display:none">
              <input type="text"  name="address2" tabindex="-1">
</div> //This is inside a form
```

ASP code:

```
var_jam_jar = Request.Form("address2")
If IsEmpty(var_jam_jar ) = true Then
```

Coming from a PHP background I'd normally just check if the input value isset or isempty. How would I go about doing this in asp classic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the value is an empty string:

```
If Trim(var_jam_jar ) = "" Then
```

In VBScript,[the IsEmpty function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cs4befa%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)  is used to determine if individual variables are initialized,